# Encrypt a column using PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, encryption

I want to encrypt a column using PostgreSQL. But I don't want the data in DB/Table to be encrypted. While querying/extracting the data from DB, I just want 'adsid' column to be encrypted in the output. Data in 'adsid' column is like a123456-111-dd43-123r-xdf1we3456z999. How can I do that?

Comment: You can do it within Postgres with [pgcrypto](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgcrypto.html). Or you can do it in your application using whatever encryption functions your programming language and framework provides.

Comment: @Schwern Can you give me the query, if possible?

Comment: See "Column-level encryption" in this blog post. https://www.enterprisedb.com/postgres-tutorials/how-implement-column-and-row-level-security-postgresql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto;

SELECT 'column_name', crypt('column_name', gen_salt('md5')) AS hashed_value
FROM 'table_name';
```

Also, you can encrypt using 'sha1' instead of 'md5' as well. It is as below:

```
SELECT 'column_name', encode(digest("column_name",'sha1'),'hex') AS hashed_value
FROM 'table_name';
```

Comment: have to say, `crypt()` is something like man 3 crypt: 
`irreversibly` “hash” phrase